# How to cut a string after specific character in shell?

Tags: shell

I have this string

localhost:32121/root/docker_registry/aiindevops.azurecr.io/msbuild:0.1

i want to extract this "aiindevops.azurecr.io/msbuild:0.1" value from above.

Comment: please be clear in asking https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify which part of the string is an exact recurring pattern.
I'm going to assume `localhost:32121/root/docker_registry/` never changes.

Then, one among the many ways to achieve this is a simple regex substitution with `sed` (note: I used `|` instead of the usual `/` for readibility, to avoid escaping the `/`'s in the URL):

```
$ echo "localhost:32121/root/docker_registry/aiindevops.azurecr.io/msbuild:0.1" | sed -Ee 's|localhost:32121/root/docker_registry/(.+)|\1|'

aiindevops.azurecr.io/msbuild:0.1
```

Another one uses `cut`, with `/` as field separator, and outputting from field 4 to the end:

```
$ echo "localhost:32121/root/docker_registry/aiindevops.azurecr.io/msbuild:0.1" | cut -d '/' -f4-

aiindevops.azurecr.io/msbuild:0.1
```